# Hibernate: Replacing object (OneToOne)

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a parent entity `Stock` which has a child entity `StockDetails` in a OneToOne relation.
I can't figure out how to properly set and replace values for the `Stock.details` field.

Here are my entity classes (@Getter/@Setter from Lombok):

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "stocks")
public class Stock
{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private long id;

  private String isin;
  private String symbol;
  private String name;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "stock", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private List<StockChartPoint> chart;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "stock", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private StockDetails details;

  public void setDetails(StockDetails d)
  {
    details = d;
    details.setStock(this);
  }

}
```

and

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "stock_details")
public class StockDetails
{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private long id;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "stock")
  private Stock stock;
}
```

Inserting a new value (and corresponding row) into the DB works fine when the details table is empty and I can see that Hibernate logs exactly one intert statement. My code looks like this:

```
dbService.transactional(session ->
{
  var stocks = getAllStocks();
  var s = stocks.get(0);

  StockDetails n = new StockDetails();
  s.setDetails(n);
  session.save(s);
});
```

The `DbService.transactional` method (`TransactionExecutor` is just a functional interface):

```
public void transactional(TransactionExecutor executor)
{
  Transaction t = null;
  try
  {
    t = session.beginTransaction();
    executor.execute(session);
    session.flush();
    t.commit();
  }
  catch (HibernateException ex)
  {
    if (t != null)
      t.rollback();
  }
}
```

But when there is already an existing row in the details table the old row is deleted and a new row is inserted. The result is that the PK of the details table is increasing every time I update the values. Is there a pattern which I couldn't find to address this? I could also just update the existing `Stock.details` field but this would lead in just copying all the fields from object A to object B and I guess there is a smarter way doing this. I tried using an `EntityManager`, `merge()/saveOrUpdate()/persist()` instead of `save()` as well as manipulating the ID in the new object but this resulted in changing nothing or throwing exceptions.

Then there is another problem I encountered and I don't know if it's related to the first one:
When executing the `dbService.transactional(...)` block twice it behaves differently: Now two rows are added to the DB. The SQL log looks like this:

```
...
Hibernate: insert into stock_details (stock) values (?)
Hibernate: delete from stock_details where id=?
-> insert/delete produces by the first run
Hibernate: select stock0_.id as id1_3_, stock0_.isin as isin2_3_, stock0_.name as name3_3_, 
stock0_.symbol as symbol4_3_ from stocks stock0_
Hibernate: insert into stock_details (stock) values (?)
-> Just insert, no delete
```

Please let me know if more information is needed.

- mysql.mysql-connector-java > 8.0.22
- org.hibernate.hibernate-core > 5.4.25.Final
- org.hibernate.hibernate-validator > 5.4.3.Final

Answer (score 1):

> But when there is already an existing row in the details table the old row is deleted...

...which is to be expected with `orphanRemoval = true`

> ...and a new row is inserted

...which is obviously to be expected as well, since you're overwriting the existing `StockDetails` associated with `s` with a brand new instance of `StockDetails`.

If you wish to update the existing `StockDetails`, rather than create a new `StockDetails` entity, you need to, well, do just that in Java code.

> I could also just update the existing Stock.details field but this would lead in just copying all the fields from object A to object B...

that would be the least error-prone approach

> ...but I guess there is a smarter way doing this

You could just do:

```
StockDetails n = new StockDetails();
n.setId(s.getStockDetails().getId());
... //configure the remaining properties
n.setStock(s);
entityManager.merge(n);
```

Comment: Completely ignore the merge part, so +1 for that. It is because projects I am involved mostly do only partial updates from DTO so it would reset all the other fields to NULL and also usually the ID of the entity is made not settable.

Answer (score 0):

As you might have guessed you are actually creating a new `StockDetails` and replacing the old one. If you want to update the existing `StockDetails` you really need to fetch that and update it field by field (as you told you could do). So like:

```
StockDetails sd = s.getStockDetails();
sd.setSomeFiled(updateValue);
// ... copying field by field
```

To prevent copying field by field you can obtain `StockDetails` from the database and make the possible edits directly into it so there would not be a need to copy each field.

However if it is a case - for example - that you need to write values from some DTO to your entity there are libraries that you can use to ease the pain of copying.

Just to mention one `ModelMapper`. With it the copying goes like:

```
ModelMapper mm = new ModelMapper();
StockDetails sd = s.getStocDetails();
mm.map(stockDetailsDto, sd);
```

where `stockDetailsDto` is some DTO object that contains fields to update to entity.

If your `StockDetails` contains all the other fields also even those not changed the `em.merge` is most easy as told in [answer from crizzis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65170601/6413377).

But if you get only the updated fields then the other fields would be set to null. Sometimes id is not settable and then merge is impossible.